# How to align overflowing text?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to have centered text even if it overflows, so that the animation of reducing the font size looks better.

```
    @Composable
    fun Test() {
        Text(
            text = "Hello there!",
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            fontSize = 50.sp,
            softWrap = false,
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
        )
    }
```

[image: aligned properly]

Is there a way to allow the overflowing text to go left?

[image: font size too big, not aligned]

Comment: `TextAlign.Center` instead of `TextAlign.End`?

Comment: @Abby Indeed, but I wanted to emphasize that the overflow doesn't go left.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Could you give a working example of your animation and explain how it's different from what you want?

Comment: @Abby I am reducing the font size if the text overfits `if (result.hasVisualOverflow) { fontSize *= 0.99`. This results in a 2 step [animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1FCW.gif). I want to align the overflowing text so that it looks like only the font size is changing without any movements/sliding.